# Automatic Trasfers from one Google Drive account to another

Tags: google-drive-api, data-transfer, flysystem-google-drive

Is there a service or feature that will allow to feed specific google drive folder from one account to another regularly (for example every few days)?

I need this for stock management.
The plan is to have a Drive folder where customers can view the inventory but I need to feed that folder (both add and remove images) from other suppliers drive accounts.
And because this involves 100s of images I need a service or bot that will add newly uploaded supplier images to my drive and remove the images that supplier removes from their drive.

Thank you in advance.

PS. it needs to be done via Google Drive because this is what suppliers use in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For your request, I think Pabbly Connect would be the best solution. You will need to create a `Google Drive Automation Workflow`, that will allow you to connect two different Google Drive accounts and automatically copy files uploaded from one account to another, as you wish.

I've used the service and it works great, you can sign up for free and test the workflow.

[image]

By the way here you have the video that explains everything about how to create the workflow you are looking for and provides more information about the service: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0DUxaKZ144**

There isn't a built-in feature in Google Drive that works exactly how you need it to, but if you are interested in contributing a [Feature idea](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/cmp-p/grouphub%3Aworkspace-ideas-group), you are welcome to do so.